# D3JS : Drawing a force-directed graph with nodes positioned from top to bottom as per their priority

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, geometry

I have a topologically sorted order of a graph. I want to draw a force-directed graph(specifically a tree) using D3JS, such that nodes are placed from top to bottom as per their position in the topologically sorted array like a tree.

If node2 and node3 depends on node1, then node2 and node3 should be below node1 in the graph, and node2 and node3 should be on the same label.I have approx 60-70 nodes to show on  a small screen. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Here is an example of a vertical tree. It's not force-directed. Correct me if I'm wrong here, but I think with a force-directed layout, you wouldn't be able to control which nodes are on top and which are on bottom.

Comment: I can't find the link for the vertical tree you mentioned. Can you please post the link. Also, i don't know whether it is possible to accomplish a vertical tree using force layout or not.

Comment: Oops. Sorry forgot to include the link. https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/b024fcce8b4b9264011a1c3e7c7d70dc

Comment: I was looking for something like this :- https://nylen.io/d3-process-map/graph.php

Comment: Hey I have a similar requirement. Did you find any solution?